# How can I create a way to bulk cut audio?

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to create an automated way to cut .mp3 files to 45 seconds.

So far I have been able to use ffmpeg to cut the audio to 45 seconds with this command:

```
ffmpeg -t 45 -i input.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp3
```

However this does not actually speed anything up, as if I have to do this with each file I might as well use audacity. I know that I should be able to use a .bat file to create a loop for this, however I don't know how to set up the loop. In python I would create a list of the file names in my directory with listdir:

`fileNames = listdir(path)`,

and then create a for loop:

(something like

```py
i = 1

for fileName in fileNames:

    x = 2 * int(i)

    ffmpeg -t 45 -i str(fileName)+'.mp3' -acodec copy str(x)+'.mp3'
```

that)

However I don't know how to create something like this in a .bat file. Some help with this, or a way to achieve this in python, would be much appreciated.

Comment: `However this does not actually speed anything up, as if I have to do this with each file I might as well use audacity.` this statament makes no sense for me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think he means that this process isn't as efficient doing it for each file compared to opening the file in audacity and doing it manually.

Comment: Your python syntax is clearly off. But a batch file is simply a set of commands. So loop through the file names and print the command to a file with a `.bat` file extension. The original file name will probably have the `.mp3` with it so you don't need to append that. Once you have a batch file that looks about right, let us know what kind of errors you may be getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using below script. Save the code into a *.bat file in the folder where you have your mp3 songs and execute it and it will process all your songs.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 1
for %%f in (*.mp3) do (
    set "output=!count!.mp3"
    ffmpeg -t 45 -i %%f -acodec copy !output!
    set /a count+=1
)
endlocal
```

Comment: You need to incrment the counter somewhere,  `set /a count+=1` also to have actual values it should be `set "output=!count!.mp3"`

Comment: yeah yeah, I missed that. Let me modify the answer